# How to disable background during loader is showing

Tags: html, css, loader

I am showing loader when user clicks on button. 
Following is the loader class

```
.loader-box{ background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:100;}
```

My problem is when loader is showing then user can move cursor by using tabs and click submit also, how to prevent this? Is this possible using any css property or do i need to do anything else ?

Comment: Unless you want to remove the submit button/other relevant elements via display:none or similar while your loader is displayed - no, this can’t be done using CSS alone. You will need some JavaScript that disables those elements temporarily.

Comment: Why not disable buttons when showing loader. Or even better make the function called by the button check if you finished loading before execution.

Comment: @CBroe can u plz suggest the javascript code which will disable the background.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting a example to help u. We can use "tabindex" attribute to focus the element when using tab key.

```
<div class="loader-box">
    <div class="formwrapper">
        <input type="text" name="name" tabindex="01" placeholder="text 01">
        <input type="text" name="name" tabindex="02" placeholder="text 02">
        <input type="text" name="name" tabindex="03" placeholder="text 03">
        <input type="button" name="button" tabindex="04" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .loader-box { 
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
        position:fixed; 
        bottom:0; 
        left:0; 
        top:0; 
        width:100%; 
        height:100%; 
        z-index:100;
    }
    .formwrapper {
        font-family: arial;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        margin:auto;
        position:fixed; 
        bottom:0; 
        left:0; 
        top:0;
        right: 0; 
        text-align: center;
        color: #000;
        background: #c1c1c1;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    input {
        padding: 5px;
        width: 80%;
        margin:8px 10px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your loader to a div that fills the page:

```
#loaderParent{
position: fixed;
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

Or if you have problem to show/hide this div make the loader itself fill the page:

```
 .loader-box{
     position: fixed;
     width:100vw;
     height:100vh;
 }
```

To prevent keyboard:

```
  $(document).keydown(function () { return false; });
```

and after fading the loader change it back:

```
 $(document).keydown(function () { return true; });
```

A sample:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Test Tab" />
<input type="button" value="Test Tab" />
<input type="button" value="Test Tab" /><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Disable KeyDown" onclick="DisableKeyDown()" />





<script>
  function DisableKeyDown(){
       $(document).keydown(function () { return false; });
       }
</script>
```

Comment: At most that will stop the user from clicking - but it won’t prevent keyboard navigation.

Comment: *My problem is when loader is showing then user can move cursor by using tabs and click submit also*, I don't think he want keyboard navigation when loader is working.

Comment: I think _“by using tabs”_ means keyboard navigation.

Comment: Yes of course *by using tabs* means keyboard navigation, but it is the thing that he want to prevent that.

Comment: Yes, and that is my point: Your answer does not provide anything that would stop keyboard navigation within the form from happening. Overlaying an element on top of all other elements might stop _mouse clicks_, but it does nothing in regard to keyboard navigation.

Comment: yes i want to prevent any activity on background, keyboard navigation using tab should not work.

Comment: Can't he check for a key press and ``return null`` or disable the form elements with JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry, Finally i find what you want, I updated the answer and i think now it works how you need.

Comment: Nothing is working @FarzinKanzi i also tried keyup in ur code.

Comment: I do not know why you say *Nothing is working*, so I put a sample for you to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable input:

```
     $("#...").attr('disabled','disabled'); // disable
     $("#...").removeAttr('disabled'); //enable
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/R95qu